# How to retrieve value for ng-bind locator in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ng-bind

The code line is:

```
class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-bind="item.name">Soap
```

Its a drop down and I want to select the value 'soap'.

Comment: Do you want to select the dropdown?  Or retrieve it's value?  those are two different things

Comment: Please post more HTML. It is difficult to see how your dropdown is represented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getAttribute` on the selected element :

```
expect(element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Soap')).getAttribute('class')).toContain('ng-bind');
```